# Hide language for anonymous users

Tags: i18n-l10n

How do I hide a language from anonymous users while I'm working on the translation?

I want the language only to be displayed in the language switcher block and the links to be active, while you are logged in as an administrator, so that they can check the translation while they are working on it.

Comment: Would simply hiding the language switcher block solve your problem?

Comment: As long as there are only two languages - yes. But if they want to add a third language thats no longer an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On our site, we're using the [Language Dropdown](http://drupal.org/project/lang_dropdown) module to display translation links.

When we want a language to be accessible to authenticated users only, so that they can translate the contents before showing them to site visitors, we hack the module this way, in lang_dropdown.module, line 192 :

```
  // @TODO TEMPORARY FIX TO DISABLE ITALIAN TO ANONYMOUS USERS
  global $user;
    if ($user->uid == 0) {
    unset($languages->links['it']);
  }
  // ENDTODO
  //
  // Now we iterate on $languages to build the needed options for the select element.
  foreach ($languages->links as $lang_code => $lang_options) {
```

Be aware that in this case, the italian contents are not really hidden for someone who would know their paths, but it's sufficient for us.

Comment: My fear is that the content gets indexed by accident before they are finished...

Comment: It depends on your site architecture. If there isn't any entry point, no homepage, nothing in sitemap.xml, Google, acting as an anonymous user, won't see anything. That's what we do, we have a hidden language on a production site since 2 months now, and nothing has been indexed...

Answer (score 0):

There is also 2 modules that can help with this

### [language_access](https://www.drupal.org/project/language_access)

which gives permissions per language

### [hidden_language](https://www.drupal.org/project/hidden_language)

which give permissions as to what roles can access hidden languages

They are both working in Drupal 7 and 8 and they are able to hide those pages from anonymous and bots.